# pandas expand rows with alternative names (multiple and change rows)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to format following dataframe (it can be copied to clipboard and read by pd ):

[image]

Given the dictionary where for each `country` there is a list of alternative names, I am trying to "explode" values with duplicate rows where `country` values are updated.
Dictonary to update country_names:

```
{
    'UAE':['United Arab Emirates', 'UAE'],
    'Rep of Tunisia': ['Tunisia','Rep of Tunisia']
}
```

desired result:

[image]

It seemed like an easy thing but I stuck, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) your dictionary, then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
out = (df.assign(country=df['country'].map(country_names))
         .explode('country', ignore_index=True)
       )
```

output:

```
                country      period
0  United Arab Emirates  2022-01-01
1                   UAE  2022-01-01
2               Tunisia  2022-10-01
3        Rep of Tunisia  2022-10-01
```

Comment: Wow, you are a savior, this works! Thanks! I will go now read a bit df.assign docs